# Adding a prefix to a form label for translation

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have  some `*Type` form classes and a `forms.html.twig` to customize form appearance. By default, in this file the labels are rendered with this block:

```
<label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans }}</label>
```

I'd like to add a prefix to the label ir order to organize my translations. For example let's say I have a `CustomerType`, then I'd like my labels to be like:

```
<label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
  {{ 'Customer.' ~ label|trans }}
</label>
```

I want to be able to pass that `'Customer'` string to the FormBuilder in such a way that I am able to use it like:

```
<label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
  {{ prefix ~ '.' ~ label|trans }}
</label>
```

or maybe:

```
<label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
  {{ form.prefix ~ '.' ~ label|trans }
}</label>
```

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Symfony 2.1

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class FieldTypeExtendedExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('label_prefix', $options['label_prefix']);
    }

    public function buildView(FormViewInterface $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $labelPrefix = $form->getRoot()->hasAttribute('label_prefix') ? $form->getRoot()->getAttribute('label_prefix') : '';
        $view->setVar('label', $labelPrefix.$view->getVar('label'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'label_prefix' => ''
        ));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

Declare this extension as a service

```
<service id="form.type_extension.fieldextended" class="MyProject\MyBundle\Form\Extension\FieldTypeExtendedExtension">
    <tag name="form.type_extension" alias="form" />
</service>
```

For more informations, [see the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html).

Answer (score 2):

To do that, just set the label explicitly:

```php
$builder->add('firstName', 'text', array(
    'label' => 'customer.first_name'
));
```

Comment: I know, I just wanted to find a way to make it a "default" behavior... When you manage many forms and many fields per form, this solution becomes pretty boring and error prone. I'd love something like `$builder->setLabelPrefix('customer')->add('firstName')->add('lastName')...`
));`

Comment: The “magic era” is subsiding. Now more and more frameworks are striving towards making more and more stuff explicit. What you want is magic and I'm not sure it's a good idea. But if you really need it, I think you might be on your own and will have to solve this problem yourself, because the community is headed in another direction.

Comment: I think there's a bit of difference between "magic" and DRY, which is what I am trying to achieve. In my little example the label prefix is explicit and the expected behavior of `setLabelPrefix` would be to add the prefix before whichever label is specified. That way I am not forced to write the field name twice or to repeat the prefix for each field.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution: "Type extension"

Create a class like this:

```php
<?php

namespace MyProject\MyBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class FieldTypeExtendedExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('label_prefix', $options['label_prefix']);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
    {
        $labelPrefix = $form->getRoot()->hasAttribute('label_prefix') ? $form->getRoot()->getAttribute('label_prefix') : '';
        $view->set('label', $labelPrefix.$form->getAttribute('label'));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'label_prefix' => '',
        );
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'field';
    }
}
```

Declare this extension as a service

```xml
<service id="form.type_extension.fieldextended" class="MyProject\MyBundle\Form\Extension\FieldTypeExtendedExtension">
    <tag name="form.type_extension" alias="field" />
</service>
```

And use this option in your form:

```php
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity, array('label_prefix' => 'mylabelprefix.'))
    ->add('link', 'url')
    ->getForm();
```

You'll have a label "mylabelprefix.link".

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the given answer didn't work, but I'm not allowed to comment. The reason it didn't work is that the `$view->getVar()` and `$view->setVar()` methods don't actually exist. To get this work, I had to make my `buildView()` method look like this:

```
public function buildView(Form\FormView $view, Form\FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    if ($options['label_prefix']) {
        $view->vars['label'] = $options['label_prefix'] . ': ' . $view->vars['label'];
    }
}
```

then set it to default to null like so:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'label_prefix' => null,
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps!